# PHP: file_get_contents does not work inside of a function

Tags: php, file-get-contents

PHP's `file_get_contents` works fine while not inside of a function. However after moving it to a function and calling that function without any other changes the code stops working.

This (outside of a function) works...

```
$cpuser = 'exampl';
$cppass = 'PASSWORD';
$cpdomain = 'example.com';
$cpskin = 'darnkids';
$emailname = 'darnkids';
$emaildomain = 'example.com';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$quota = '0';

$result1 = file_get_contents("https://$cpuser:$cppass@$cpdomain:2083/frontend/$cpskin/mail/doaddpop.html?email=$emailname&domain=$emaildomain&password=$password&quota=$quota");
echo $result1;
```

---

This same code (inside of a function) does not work...

```
$cpuser = 'exampl';
$cppass = 'PASSWORD';
$cpdomain = 'example.com';
$cpskin = 'darnkids';
$emailname = 'darnkids';
$emaildomain = 'example.com';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$quota = '0';

function account_create()
{
 $result1 = file_get_contents("https://$cpuser:$cppass@$cpdomain:2083/frontend/$cpskin/mail/doaddpop.html?email=$emailname&domain=$emaildomain&password=$password&quota=$quota");
 echo $result1;
}

account_create();
```

I need to be able to capture the response regardless of what it is. Why is `file_get_contents` not working while inside a function and how do I get it to work inside of a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `file_get_contents()`. The function doesn't have those global variables in its scope.

You need to make them available either with the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword or the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array, or better still, scope them to your function.

Comment: Derp, yeah can't believe I did that. Thanks, will accept after the limitation is lifted.

Answer (score 1):

When you move the call to file_get_contents into a function the variables you're using to define the filename are local versions, which aren't defined in your function. Either move the variables into the function, pass them as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alex states above, the global variables aren't available. If you'd rather not define globals (for whatever reason) just make sure your function encloses all of the data in your first snippet. Something like this.

```
function account_create(){
$cpuser = 'exampl';
$cppass = 'PASSWORD';
$cpdomain = 'example.com';
$cpskin = 'darnkids';
$emailname = 'darnkids';
$emaildomain = 'example.com';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$quota = '0';
$result1 = file_get_contents("https://$cpuser:$cppass@$cpdomain:2083/frontend/$cpskin/mail/doaddpop.html?email=$emailname&domain=$emaildomain&password=$password&quota=$quota");
 echo $result1;
}

account_create();
```

If that doesn't work for your use-case, you can always pass some or all of the data TO the function instead. Such as...

```
function account_create($cp_user, $cppass){
    ...
}

account_create('example1', 'PASSWORD');
```

Lots of options available to you. Hope that was somewhat helpful.